# Does the preprocessor prepare a list of unique constant strings before the compiler goes into action?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, c-strings

In the code below, I have two **different** local `char*` variables declared in two **different** functions.

Each variable is initialized to point to a constant string, and the contents of the two strings are identical.

Checking in runtime, the variables are initialized to point to the same address in memory.

So the compiler must have assigned the same (constant) value to each one of them.

**How is that possible?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintPointer()
{
    char* p = "abc";
    printf("%p\n",p);
}

int main()
{
    char* p = "abc";
    printf("%p\n",p);
    PrintPointer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly *how* the compiler does this might differ between compilers. Compilers doesn't actually have to do this. This is all compiler-specific. And the preprocessor is not involved in any way in this.

Comment: Oh, and as you say, you make the pointers point to *constant* strings, but still the variables aren't declared as that. Either do `char const* p = ...` or the more traditional `const char* p = ...`

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: The question is not about `const`, and adding `const` does not change the fact that the two variables are pointing to the same memory address. True, one should declare it `const` in order to avoid runtime exception when attempting to change the contents of the strings. But that's not the issue in this question.

Comment: By the way, this is called _string pooling optimization_.

Comment: I didn't say that the constness of the variable declarations was an issue here. But when you declare a pointer to non-const data, and make it point to const data, you open yourself up for undefined behavior.

Comment: @rodrigo: compiler optimizations are disabled (I should have mentioned that).

Comment: @barakmanos: Usually, compilers don't just offer a single "Optimization? Yes/No" flag but allow for a more granular configuration.

Comment: @barakmanos: The fact that you disable compiler optimizations doesn't mean that the compiler will not apply some techniques that could be called trivial optimizations. If you use GCC (just guessing) you can use `-fwritable-strings` to disable the string pooling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the *preprocessor*. But the *compiler* is explicitly allowed (not required) by the standard to share the memory for identical string literals. For details on when this happens, you must consult your compiler's documentation.

For example, here's the relevant [documentation for VC2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx):

> In some cases, identical string literals may be pooled to save space in the executable file. In string-literal pooling, the compiler causes all references to a particular string literal to point to the same location in memory, instead of having each reference point to a separate instance of the string literal. To enable string pooling, use the /GF compiler option.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard says in N3797 2.14.15/12:

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

The C standard now contains the same wording. Historically it was possible to modify string literals at run-time in C, but this is now Undefined Behaviour. Some compilers may allow it, some not.

Technically, the compiler does it by storing string literals in the symbol table. If an identical string is seen more than once, the same symbolic reference is used each time. The same technique might well be used for other literals, but would not be so easily detected.

The preprocessor, by the way, has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

> How is that possible?

It's *possible* because the compiler keeps track of values like that. But no, the preprocessor generally doesn't get involved in things like this; the preprocessor does things like macro substitutions that modify the code before the compiler starts working. In this case, though, we're talking about actual code:

```
char* p = "abc";
```

and that's the domain of the compiler, not the preprocessor.

Comment: Thinking of how the compiler can "know" of all `abc` strings in the program, the only conclusion is that it gathers this information **before** compiling the code. So I've assumed this as a pre-compilation "activity" (perhaps I should have used this term instead of "preprocessor").

Comment: @barakmanos: That's linguistic nitpicking. Compiling is not a linear process, i.e. the compiler doesn't just compile source code one line after the other. It has to "look ahead" for all but the simplest pieces of code, anyway.

Comment: @barakmanos In addition to the "look ahead" mentioned by Christian, the compiler of course stores lot of data about things it already have seen. So when it has seen the string literal in one function, it knows about it. So when it sees another string literal it can compare it to previous string literals it have already read. How it does this comparison is up to the compiler, but it's likely it's using some kind of hash-table.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: It doesn't do so over different files, though, right? (although I can check it myself).

Comment: @barakmanos: Depends on the compiler (which you still have not named). But a compiler can of course do so over different files. The standard doesn't care. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> So the compiler must have assigned the same (constant) value to each one of them. How is that possible?

If you have two identical string literals, as you do here, then the compiler is allowed to combine them into a single one; apparently, your compiler does that. It's also allowed to store them separately.

Comment: So this is not a part of the standard then?

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes, it is. The standard *allows* it. But it doesn't *require* it. So it would also be standards-compliant as well if it stored the literals separately.

Comment: @barakmanos: No; the standard leaves it implementation-defined. To quote C++11: "Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined." I'm sure C says something similar.